# Having an issue coloring custome xml button

Tags: android, android-button

I'm having an issue coloring a custom button. For some reason, it seems like no matter what coloring change I want to apply (text or background) the button remains the same.

I notice the `button.xml` has the desired color and the right shape though it doesn't appear the button `background-color` property on the activity

**the button from an activity**

```
   <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="162dp"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button"
        android:text="@string/button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.132"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/messagTextView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.804" />
```

**custome button shape**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape android:shape="rectangle" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="50sp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/redAdobeXD"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [material components](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel) (which is probably the case if this is a relatively new project) then you style the `Button` in another way:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"
        android:text="I am a Button!"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        app:cornerRadius="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Things to notice are:

- `style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"`
- `android:textColor="@color/white"`
- `app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"` (would be `@color/redAdobeXD` in your case)
- `app:cornerRadius="50dp"`

There is no need for an extra xml and setting that on the button etc. (only in more custom cases).

You can read more about available options on the *ContainedButton* [here](https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons#contained-button)