# Android Button background color not changing on xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

- Android Stidio 4.1.1

  - SDK 29 (Android 10)

I trying to change button background color on xml, but it doesn't changed.

here's my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ff0000"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFaJH.png)

I think it might be work fine, but it still purple color :(

Comment: Does it change the color in the application after build?

Comment: @ZankrutParmar  Nope, it still purple color

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50884131/8227346

Comment: You have a custom theme named 'Test' applied in the editor. What is the parent of that theme?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having an issue coloring custome xml button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65202859/having-an-issue-coloring-custome-xml-button)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you are using Android Studio 4.1.1 you are probably using Theme.MaterialComponents
check your themes.xml file

[image]

so you have to use this attribute

```
android:backgroundTint="#ff0000"
```

read this documentation for more information:

https://material.io/components/buttons

If you insist on using android:background you can change your button xml code like this to force it using appcompat :

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

or you can change the theme of all your project by changing the  theme in themes.xml like this:

[image]

I hope this is useful.

Comment: it work, 
but i really doest need backgroundTint option.
there's any way to use only background ?

Comment: if you are using android studio 4.1.1 you probably using Theme.MaterialComponents "check the themes.xml in your project" if you use background attribute it will use the default color. read this documentation https://material.io/components/buttons

Comment: thx for the great answer, I think It would be better to use a different kind of theme. or downgrade Android Studio version :(

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your java code.

```
button1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));
```

Answer (score 0):

May be Android Studio is showing you the cached view for xml. Try changing Emulator from above where it is selected **Custom** as per your image. If it doesn't update the colour, try **Invalidate Cache and Restart** you Android Studio

Comment: thx for the answer :D
but it still doest work ... :(

Comment: Is your theme **Theme.MaterialComponents** or **Theme.AppCompat**? Try to make your style **Theme.MaterialComponents**

Answer (score 0):

Ensure all your app dependencies in your build.gradle(app) file are latest.

The latest as of 4th Feb 2021 in android studio 4.1.1 are the following

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

if it's not much important, change Button to TextView and set background, it's working as magicially ;))